# Activate man in Mac for MySQL

Tags: mysql, macos, manpage

I installed MAMP on my Mac and it installed everything needed such as Apache, MySQL and so on and I can use everything w/o any problem but when I try to say `man mysql` to read manual on the Terminal, this is the error I receive:

> No manual entry for mysql

I did some Google searches but haven't seen anything useful except for manpagez.com which is online documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do `mysql --help` to get all the help for mysql. Is there something specific that you want about man command that you can't do with `mysql --help`

Comment: This is the error I got after typing that command in: `-bash: mysql: command not found`

Comment: @Braveyard mysql is not in your path. You need to provide the full path or you can do something like `sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql /usr/local/bin/mysql` to put a symlink in your local bin dir which should be in your path.

Answer (score 1):

MAMP is different from actually installing unix stuff.

For unix type stuff like manpages, see macports: http://www.macports.org/  This will also allow you do install things like `wget` as you would normally do via `apt-get`.

Note MAMP is the only way I've actually gotten this stuff to get the full XAMP stack working on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

In terminal **navigate to your mysql** install, usually in a location like /usr/local/mysql

Then type  at the $ prompt: **man -M ./man mysql**
or: man -M ./man mysqld_safe

I'm not sure where to get a full list of what's in the mySQL man pages, but at least its a start.

as stated before 
$: **mysql --help** is useful too